# Distorted sound when changing AVAudioPlayer's rate var in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, audio, swift2, avaudioplayer

I'm working on a simple audio playback app. It has approximately 10 audio files, each with a normal playback tempo of 100 beats per minute. The user is able to input a tempo variable (between 70 and 140 b.p.m.) which is assigned (tempo/100) to the AVAudioPlayer rate var, just before the play() function is called...

```
@IBAction func playPause(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !isPlaying {
        let audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(selectedTrack, ofType: "mp3")
        do {
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))
            player.enableRate = true
            player.rate = Float(tempo) / 100
            player.play()
            isPlaying = !isPlaying
        } catch {
            print ("play error")
        }
     }
}
```

Playback at the audio's normal tempo (100b.p.m.) works perfectly fine. However, by changing the tempo by even a single bpm unit, the playback sounds really poor. The tempo shift sounds accurate (i.e. lowering the tempo var results in the audio slowing down, and vice versa), and the pitch sounds like it is maintained (albeit, a little 'wobbly' in sustained notes), but the quality of the sound seems to be negatively affected in a major way. I would perhaps expect this for more extreme rate changes (rate<50% or rate>200%), but it is totally apparent even at 99% and 101%.

I was using 44k/16bit .wav, then tried .mp3 (in a variety of qualities), all with the same result. I've also looked at this, which seems similar if not the same (though the query was never resolved)... [AVAudioPlayer rate change introduces artifacts/distortion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128172/avaudioplayer-rate-change-introduces-artifacts-distortion)

Changing the playback speed of these files using other software (DAWs and virtual DJ softs) does not create the same anomalies, so my assumption is that perhaps the algorithm that interpolates the extra data points on the waveform is simply not robust enough for my purpose.

But if anyone can give me a solution, I'd be totally stoked.

Comment: This looks like a good answer/explanation: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4797

Comment: You are a total legend @EricD I'll give this a shot