# Poor Audio Quality changing avPlayer.rate in Mac OS Swift 3

Tags: macos, audio, avplayer

Playing either mp3 or mp4 (local files) or m3u8 (streaming) on AVPlayer. 
The audio quality is good.
However, as a soon as I change AVPlayer.rate to anything other than 1.0 (e.g. 0.8 or 1.2).... the audio quality is poor.
This is on Mac OS.

Note: I've raised a bug to Apple (id 30497462) for this as well, but I thought I'd check if anyone here has any thoughts. If Apple respond to my ticket, I'll update this for everyone.

I have tried to change the audioTimePitchAlgorithm - I've tried all possible values: AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmTimeDomain, AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmSpectral (the default) and AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmVarispeed, but they all sound equally bad as soon as AVPlayer.rate is changed

Have tried building in Release configuration as well as Debug configuration - same result.

There are a few related StockOverflow threads on this, most notable this: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37687122/distorted-sound-when-changing-avaudioplayers-rate-var-in-swift-2-0), but the advice is to change the audioTimePitchAlgorithm - which, as I explained above is not helping, or to try various things with AVAudioPlayer - but I'm needing to play videos.

If there's some sort of workaround (e.g. are there other video players for Mac?, or can I divert the sound through to an AVPlayer?) then I'd be interested in pursuing that.

I am wondering if my hardware's a bit too old for this, my spec is:
MacBook Pro (13", Late 2011)
Processor: 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory: 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB

Code is:

```
import AVFoundation
```

class ViewController: NSViewController {

```
let avPlayer = AVPlayer()
var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

@IBOutlet weak var speedBtn: NSButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let view = self.view

    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    view.layer?.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

    let url = // TODO - add "PATH TO MP3 or MP4"
    //let streamingUrl = NSURL(string: "https://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/vM7nH0Kl.m3u8") as! URL

    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    avPlayerLayer.frame = view.bounds
}

@IBAction func speedBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    avPlayer.rate = 0.99
}

@IBAction func normalBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    avPlayer.rate = 1.0
}
override func viewWillAppear() {
    avPlayer.play() // Start the playback
}
```

}